# binding href and click event both in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

In the below sample I have a collection called `DList`. (ignore syntax error if any). In the given list it contains 3 rows. Now in the UI for each row I have tab collection named 'CustomerTab' and 'ProductTab'. I have used anchor tag which has the `href` and also the `click` event. I expect the click event to be fired and then show the desired tab
which is clicked by the user. In the UI by default I am showing the 'CustomerTab' . If I click on the 'ProductTab' event is getting fired but the HTML contents of the 'ProductTab' is not being shown.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="frmTest" ng-app="enc" ng-controller="encMain">
        <div ng-repeat="D in DList">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" id="CustomerTab" aria-expanded="false" ng-attr-xlink:href="{{D.CustomerTab}}" ng-click="CustomerTabClick(D)">Customer</a></li>
                <li><a data-toggle="tab" id="ProductTab" aria-expanded="true" ng-attr-xlink:href="{{D.ProductTab}}" ng-click="PTabClick(D)">Product</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-content">
            <section class="tab-pane fade active in" ng-attr-id={{D.CustomerTabContent}}>
                <p>customerBlock</p>
            </section>
            <section class="tab-pane fade in" ng-attr-id={{D.ProductTabContent}}>
                <p>ProductBlock</p>
            </section>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem I am facing in angularjs is that I need the `click` event to be fired first which is working and then the hyperlink also should work. 
The problem here is now that hyperlink is not working.

```
   var app = angular.module('enc', []);
app.controller('encMain', function ($scope) {
    $scope.DList = [];

    function addDList(rowId, dName, customertab, producttab,customertabContent,producttabContent) {
        return {
            RowId: rowId,
            DName: dName,
            CustomerTab: customertab,
            ProductTab: producttab,
            CustomertabContent: customertabContent,
            ProducttabContent: producttabContent
        }
    }

    $scope.CustomerTabClick = function (data) {
        alert('Customer');
        //Processing some data on the click event and then returning true value
        return true;
    }

    $scope.PTabClick = function (data) {
        alert('Product');
        //Processing some data on the click event and then returning true value
        return true;
    }

    $scope.DList.push(new addDList('1', 'Catalog1', 'CustomerTab-1-1', 'ProductTab-1-1', 'CustomerTab-1-1', 'ProductTab-1-1')); 
});
```

Comment: please solve syntax errors and edit the question.

Comment: code is updatenow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@jaiganesh

The reason you are not able to switch to the different tab is static css classes.

```
<div class="tab-content">
            <section class="tab-pane fade active in" ng-attr-id={{D.CustomerTabContent}}>
                <p>customerBlock</p>
            </section>
            <section class="tab-pane fade in" ng-attr-id={{D.ProductTabContent}}>
                <p>ProductBlock</p>
            </section>
        </div>
```

Look at this above code. for both the sections the classes you are applying  are static. Here first section will be always visible and second second will never be visible. In your code I cant see any mechanism to handle this scenario.

I can suggest you one scenario.. Instead of putting the static class names, put a variable.

```
<div class="tab-content">
            <section class="{{classCustomer}}" ng-attr-id={{D.CustomerTabContent}}>
                <p>customerBlock</p>
            </section>
            <section class="{{classProduct}}" ng-attr-id={{D.ProductTabContent}}>
                <p>ProductBlock</p>
            </section>
        </div>
```

Define these two variable in angularjs code

```
$scope.classCustomer = "tab-pane fade active in";
$scope.classProduct = "tab-pane fade in";
```

And you need to change these variables withing the functions as well like below

```
$scope.CustomerTabClick = function (data) {
                alert('Customer');
                $scope.classCustomer = "tab-pane fade active in";
                $scope.classProduct = "tab-pane fade in";
                //Processing some data on the click event and then returning true value
                return true;
            }

            $scope.PTabClick = function (data) {
                alert('Product');
                $scope.classCustomer = "tab-pane fade in";
                $scope.classProduct = "tab-pane fade active in";
                //Processing some data on the click event and then returning true value
                return true;
            }
```

This should completely solve your issue.

Now the full code will look like below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('enc', []);
        app.controller('encMain', function ($scope) {
            $scope.DList = [];
            $scope.classCustomer = "tab-pane fade active in";
            $scope.classProduct = "tab-pane fade in";

            function addDList(rowId, dName, customertab, producttab, customertabContent, producttabContent) {
                return {
                    RowId: rowId,
                    DName: dName,
                    CustomerTab: customertab,
                    ProductTab: producttab,
                    CustomertabContent: customertabContent,
                    ProducttabContent: producttabContent
                }
            }

            $scope.CustomerTabClick = function (data) {
                alert('Customer');
                $scope.classCustomer = "tab-pane fade active in";
                $scope.classProduct = "tab-pane fade in";
                //Processing some data on the click event and then returning true value
                return true;
            }

            $scope.PTabClick = function (data) {
                alert('Product');
                $scope.classCustomer = "tab-pane fade in";
                $scope.classProduct = "tab-pane fade active in";
                //Processing some data on the click event and then returning true value
                return true;
            }

            $scope.DList.push(new addDList('1', 'Catalog1', 'CustomerTab-1-1', 'ProductTab-1-1', 'CustomerTab-1-1', 'ProductTab-1-1'));
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="frmTest" ng-app="enc" ng-controller="encMain">
        <div ng-repeat="D in DList">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" id="CustomerTab" aria-expanded="false" ng-attr-xlink:href="{{D.CustomerTab}}" ng-click="CustomerTabClick(D)">Customer</a></li>
                <li><a data-toggle="tab" id="ProductTab" aria-expanded="true" ng-attr-xlink:href="{{D.ProductTab}}" ng-click="PTabClick(D)">Product</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-content">
            <section class="{{classCustomer}}" ng-attr-id={{D.CustomerTabContent}}>
                <p>customerBlock</p>
            </section>
            <section class="{{classProduct}}" ng-attr-id={{D.ProductTabContent}}>
                <p>ProductBlock</p>
            </section>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: problem was i have used "ng-attr-xlink:href="{{D.CustomerTab}}". Instead of this i used "ng-href" and it was working as expected.  workaraound solution suggested gave me the insight , however i was looking for better approach and i am still not sure why 'ng-attr-xlink:href' was not working